# How to set specific quality of video depending on the internet speed

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediaplayercontroller

I am having three URL for the videos, one with Low-Quality, Medium-Quality and High-Quality. Now, I want to determine the internet speed and depending on that I would like to show the video from appropriate URL and if in between, the internet speed found good then URL should be switched to high-quality one and continue playing from there.
 So, can anyone suggest how can I make it happen, I have searched for it but not be able to find any strong solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trying to build an adaptive streaming player, effectively. For Apple devices, streamed content can be served up in HLS format. Instead of building that capability, you should look for a player that can do that adaptive streaming and a server backend that can support adaptive streaming as well.

For instance, Microsoft Azure Media Services provides such functionality. They even provide a [web-based player](http://amsplayer.azurewebsites.net/azuremediaplayer.html) that you can embed in your app on a webview.

Comment: Thanks Mr Luis. I will surely check for Azure Media Services